# Can't filter aync data on mounted vuejs

Tags: arrays, firebase, vue.js, vuex

I'm working on a vuejs/(vuex) for state management/firebase project of posts.

So I have a firestore collection of posts (array of objects that have name id owner content and timestamp for creation ...)

I'm retrieving that data by using the onSnapshot methode and it's stored on blogPosts variable... and we show theme all, when a user want to visit a single post it will redirect him to the route of the single post (..../view-post/postid) and i filter that array using the id of the post to have an array of one element (which is the post he visited)

when the filter complete i got all the data and i fill theme on the template like these

```
<template>
    <NavBarView />
    <section class="preview" v-if="currentBlog">
        <h2>{{ currentBlog[0].blogTitle }}</h2>
        <p>Posted on: <span>{{ dateFormat() }}</span> <span v-if="currentBlog[0].editTime">(Last edit:
                {{ editFormat() }})</span></p>
        <img class="blogCover" :src="currentBlog[0].blogCoverFileURL" :alt="currentBlog[0].blogCoverPhoto">
        <div class="html-blog" v-html="currentBlog[0].blogHTML"></div>
        <hr />
    </section>
</template>
```

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                currentBlog: null
            }
        },
        mounted: {
            this.currentBlog = this.blogPosts.filter((post) => {
                return post.blogID == this.$route.params.id
            })
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapState(['blogPosts'])
        }
//note that i have exported all the requirements such as mapState and firebase functions ... didn't write theme here
    } 
</script>
```

now the problem is that the filter is occurring before the data are fetched from firebase and i can't handle that so it's always returning can't read property of null (currentBlog[0])

i found a solution which is sending a getDoc request to firebase but it's a bad idea, (why i send request and i have all the posts here so i can filter it directly and get the specific post) which didn't work!!!!!

any solution??

Comment: Can you edit your question and all the relevant code so we can see what the issue could probably be?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i've edited the code... i how i can find a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your template, I'm under the impression `currentBlog` should not be an array, as you don't ever have more than 1 element in that array (you're filtering by `blogID`, which I'm guessing is a unique identifier). You need to `.find()` the blog entry, not `.filter()` it:

```js
  computed: {
    blogID() {
      return this.$route.params.id;
    },
    currentBlog() {
      return this.$store.state.blogPosts.find((b) => b.blogID === this.blogID);
    }
  }
```

**Note:** if `state.blogPosts` does ***not*** start as an empty array (as it should), you might want to use:

```js
    currentBlog() {
      return (this.$store.state.blogPosts || []).find(
        (b) => b.blogID === this.blogID
      );
    }
```

And now replace all `currentBlog[0]`s with `currentBlog`:

```html
<template>
  <NavBarView />
  <section class="preview" v-if="currentBlog">
    <h2>{{ currentBlog.blogTitle }}</h2>
    <p>
      Posted on: <span>{{ dateFormat() }}</span>
      <span v-if="currentBlog.editTime">(Last edit: {{ editFormat() }})</span>
    </p>
    <img
      class="blogCover"
      :src="currentBlog.blogCoverFileURL"
      :alt="currentBlog.blogCoverPhoto"
    />
    <div class="html-blog" v-html="currentBlog.blogHTML"></div>
    <hr />
  </section>
</template>
```

---

Important: make sure in every single method/computed/watch in the script part of the component, if using `currentBlog`, you're first checking if it's not falsy. Generic example:

```js
  computed: {
    blogHTML() {
      return this.currentBlog?.blogHTML
      /* shorthand for:
       * return this.currentBlog && currentBlog.blogHTML
       */
    }
  }
```

Comment: well it's a great explaining but still the value returned is null the find is happening before the data are captured, the only solution i found was by using the getDoc meth each time to get the specific post

Comment: If you need more help you might want to provide a *runnable* [mcve].

Comment: i read your solution again and yep! that worked thaks man.

Comment: @ALLAOUAOkba, In that case mark it as the accepted answer. This tells other users with a similar problem this worked for you and also helps indexing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that rather than trying to do this operation once on `mounted` that you instead re-run the filter every time that `state.blogPosts` is updated. You can easily do this through a computed property.  See below:

```
export default {
        data() {
            return {
            }
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapState(['blogPosts']),
            currentBlog(){
              const posts = this.$store.state.blogPosts;
              if(Array.isArray(posts)) {
                  return posts.filter((post) => {
                     return post.blogID == this.$route.params.id
                  });
               } else {
                  return null
               }
            } 
       }
    }
```

Comment: still the same problem, the filter is happening before the data are captured that's why it's giving me that error now i can't figure a way to get the data THEN filter the array!!!!!

Comment: Thanks for posting your code, see edit with new solution.